# manifest does not exist - creating a new one in react native app

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, native

I'm getting `"manifest does not exist - creating a new one"` when I open my application in iOS.There is showing only the splash screen and do not pass to next screen. The xcode console show the error that i already mentioned.

If some one can help me, I will be very grateful because I have 1 week trying to fix the error but I have not found any solution for this bug

Thank you in advanced

Comment: We're you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i had a same issue 2 days ago. For me it was something related to cache.
open **projectname.workspace** file again directly from the folder and reset the simulation.